# How can I determine the exception which comes from the dll

Tags: c#, exception, assemblies

How can I determine the exception which comes from the dll

Main.exe

-subdll1.dll //dll error occurs at this, how can I find the error occurred from this dll.

-subdll2.dll

like this

delegate(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{

```
    e.ExceptionSourceAssebmly like this
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To see where an exception is defined you'll need to look at the top of the exception's [stack trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.stacktrace.aspx).

[`Exception.TargetSite`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.targetsite.aspx) *might* contain this information directly (as a [`MethodBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.aspx)), but the documentation notes it doesn't work across AppDomain boundaries.

Comment: impossible to achieve through the stacktrace and TargetSite..

stacktrace, can be useful if you have pdb file.